# Automatic syncing of data on a node that was down for a while:

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have 3 SOLR instances on 3 different hosts and an external zookeeper configured for each SOLR instance.

Suppose, instance1 and instance2 are up and running and instance3 is down. A few records are added to both the running instances.

I am able to see the records that were added to instance1 on both instance1 and instance2.

I am able to see the records that were added to instance2 on both instance1 and instance2.

Then when I bring up instance3, I don't see the records that were added to instance1 and instance2.

What needs to be done so the instance that is down can remain in sync with the running instances when it comes up?

Comment: Can you share version of Solr, OS, number of documents? Do you have any error messages in the logs for instance3?

Comment: We are using SOLR-4.3.0 on Linux. I have 30,000 documents. No error messages on log for instance 3.

Comment: Also, I only have a single shard.

Comment: Are you using SolrCloud?

Comment: yes, I am using solr cloud